# How to calculate cumulative sum for day wise in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Column Names : MonthName,Day,Start,Today,Progress,(LastColumn Is Unnecessary)

Output:

Here i want the cumulative sum of Progress.. i.e., 
For October 1 - Sum should be 0.00%
For October 2 - Sum should be 0.00+3.67% = 3.67%
For October 3 - Sum should be 3.67%+2.75% = 6.42%

In this way i want cumulative sum. Help me in this context.

Best Regards,
Yaswanth.

Answer (score 1):

power BI Matrix can do that.
Follow the below steps:

1. Under your Matrix visualization, go to your value and select "New quick measure".
2. Under the calculation list, select "Running Total".
3. Change field to your "Day" column and click "OK"

Then you should able to see what you want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZl1.png)

Comment: running total = 
CALCULATE(
 SUM('Table2'[Progress]),
 FILTER(
  ALLSELECTED('Table2'[Day]),
  ISONORAFTER('Table2'[Day], MAX('Table2'[Day]), DESC)
 )
)

Comment: Thank You Haoran.. thanks a lot actually my measure is also crrct when i followed the same steps bt th thng is tht it givng for day column but i mentioned date column so it is showng lyk tht now its wrkng fine... Thqn